# I found Knockout.js value binding has memory leak in IE8.Is this code written wrong?

Tags: knockout.js

here is a demo code from other one. It uses text binding and works ok in both IE8 and chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/haq2y/30/

but when I modified it from text binding to value binding.
http://jsfiddle.net/vfahrenheit/UtQyU/3/

I found the memory of IE8 will grow 3m-4m per click(Fake Sort button).
In Chrome It seems ok without significant memory growth.

So Is the code written wrong or caused by other problems?

Comment: What did you use to test the memory? Also, I tried both of these in stock IE8 on Windows 7, and found no memory increase. Please provide additional details.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on two different computers now. One running Windows XP, and one running Windows 7, both using IE 8. I found no memory leak in jsFiddle, or running the code in its own environment. I was unable to duplicate your problem.

I suspect you have some addon that is causing the leak.

Comment: thank you very much. this problem still exits on my computer. I'll make more tests to see whether it's caused by other factors.